# Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7fb2bc14aa90>": "Post.created_by" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a post as a logged user but when I try to do so, I get this error:

```
Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7fb2bc14aa90>": "Post.created_by" must be a "User" instance.
```

I figured there's an issue when it comes to keeping the user logged in since I did get the token and all the data when I logged it in but that seems to disappear the moment I go to another view in the API.
How can I fix it?

These are the serializers:

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    User Login Serializer
    """
    username = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        write_only=True,
    )

    token = serializers.CharField(
        allow_blank=True,
        read_only=True
    )

    password = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        write_only=True,
        style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )

    class Meta(object):
        model = User
        fields = ['id','username', 'password', 'token']

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get('username', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)

        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(request=self.context.get('request'),
                                username=username, password=password)
                                
            if not user:
                msg = 'Unable to log in with provided credentials.'
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')
        else:
            msg = "Must include username and password."
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')
        
        

        data['user'] = user
        return data

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Post Serializer
    """
    replies = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_replies')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['category','title','body','created_at','replies']
        extra_kwargs = {'created_by': {'read_only':True}}

    def get_replies(self, obj):
        serializer = PostRepliesSerializer(Post.objects.filter(reply_to=obj), many=True,
                                           context={'request': self.context.get('request')})
        return serializer.data
```

These are the views:

```
User = get_user_model()

class UserLoginAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
    serializer_class = serializers.UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({"status": status.HTTP_200_OK, "Token": token.key})

class PostAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """PostViewSet
        Post API will be used to creating new discussion, listing, and replying to a post
    """
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        """
        return Post.objects.filter(reply_to__isnull=True)

    
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(created_by=request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: How are you making requests? Postman?

Comment: @oluwakayode Yes, I've made my requests both on postman and then just in my API view but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try creating a post using the Django REST Framework user interface, while logged in?

Comment: @oluwakayode I have, but I get the same error as if I hadn't logged in.